# What's the difference between DDRB and pinMode?

Tags: pins, sketch, avr

It's my understanding that the following lines are equivalent. They seem to be interchangeable in my sketch:

```
DDRB = 1<<DDB0;
```

and

```
pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
```

Is the first form (`DDRB...`) setting a micro-controller address directly? Is that assembler?

And is the second form (`pinMode`) using an included library? Maybe the `avr/io.h` library?

*On a Digispark ATTiny85*.

Comment: They are not interchangeable. `DDRB = 1<<DDB0;` sets PB0 to output, and it also **sets every other I/O pin to input**. It's not assembler, no. In assembler you would write `sbi _SFR_IO_ADDR(DDRB), 0`.

Comment: `DDRB |= 1<<DDB0;` would be equivalent to `pinMode(0, OUTPUT);`. The latter has the side-effect of being slower though.

Comment: @EdgarBonet if not assembler, what is it? C? Is it really the same language as pinMode(), just setting lower-level bits directly? thx

Comment: It is C (or C++, they are the same for this statement). The `pinMode()` form invokes a library function which does the same thing as the other form.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Did you mean to say,'......sets every other I/O pin of Port B to input"?

Comment: @MarsSojourner: Yes, indeed. `DDRB` only controls port B.

Comment: @EdgarBonet What if you want to set only bit 5 of Port B as an input? Would the programming syntax then be DDRB = 1<<DDB5; ?

Comment: @MarsSojourner: That would set PB5 as output and all the other PBn as inputs. To set PB5 as output without touching the other pins, use `DDRB |= 1<<DDB5`. To set it as input without touching the other pins, `DDRB &= ~(1<<DDB5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, on a simple microcontroller like the ATTiny the two lines of code are equivalent.  The function `pinMode(...)` just looks up what pins relate to what ports in a table and set the right registers.

Using `DDRB` instead of `pinMode(...)` is fine as long as you are never going to run your code on anything else (or give it to anyone else to run), since you have now hard coded into your sketch what pins are to be used. It is more efficient to use `DDRB` though. You sacrifice portability for efficiency.

However, for more complex microcontrollers that have many many functions on a single pin, just manipulating `DDRB` (or the equivalent on the target microcontroller) may not be enough. You may need to switch the pin into GPIO mode, disable analog inputs on the pin, or other operations as well. All that will be wrapped up in the `pinMode(...)` function for you by the Arduino API so you don't need to worry about it.

So, in short, if you don't care about portability, and you do care about efficiency and code size (which may well be the case on an ATTiny) then yes use `DDRB` and its friends.

Comment: i understand that analogWrite() eliminates the need to enable output-mode completely -- neither DDRB nor pinMode() statements are needed. Is analogWrite() even less efficient than pinMode() + analogWrite()? -thx

Comment: The pinMode is redundant. PWM is a special mode that is not controlled by GPIO but a signal from a timer.

Comment: "as long as you are never going to run your code on anything else" --I assume the `DDRB` syntax is valid *at least* for the entire ATTiny line, if not beyond. No?

Comment: @johnywhy: It even works on the ATmegas. Note, however, that for setting pin 0 to output on an Arduino Uno you would use `DDRD` instead of `DDRB`, because pin 0 on the Uno is on port D rather than port B. With the `pinMode()` function you use the pin numbers that are printed on the silkscreen of the board, and you don't have to worry about the pin to port mapping, because the function takes care of this for you. You sacrifice efficiency for convenience.

Comment: @EdgarBonet yep, i understand the efficiency vs convenience tradeoff. Just confirming that the registers *are*, or are *not*, the same across the ATTiny family.

Comment: @johnywhy Have you heard of "datasheets"? All the registers and what they mean are in them...

Comment: I'm asking about your answer. You said "as long as you are never going to run your code on **anything** else", implying that no, the addresses are different even between different ATTiny's. Is that your intended meaning? thx

Comment: @johnywhy "anything else" even includes the same chip in a different board with different pins being needed to be manipulated. If you need to use pin B3 instead of pin B0 on a different board with the same chip you will have to change your code. Using `pinMode`, as long as both pins are numbered the same in the IDE, there will be nothing you need to change.

Answer (score 1):

> DDRB

is a register. Exactly: Port B Data Direction Register. See [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf) for ATtiny, chapter 10.4. Register Description and 10.2.1 Configuring the Pin. This part will explain why

> DDB0

value was used.
Using this way of setting direction of a pin is much faster than  `pinMode(0, OUTPUT);`
The possible problem is when you want to use same code to program different Arduino. In this case you have to remember to check all direct registers operations.