# Platform-independent functions for FastPWM?

Tags: pwm

I learned from [answers here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/48356/41397) that `pinMode(0, OUTPUT)` is a platform-independent equivalent of `DDRB = 1<<DDB0`, on the ATTiny85.

Are there platform-independent functions for the following?

```
TCCR0A = 2<<COM0A0 | 2<<COM0B0 | 3<<WGM00;
TCCR0B = 0<<WGM02 | 1<<CS00;
TCCR1 = 0<<PWM1A | 0<<COM1A0 | 1<<CS10;
GTCCR = 1<<PWM1B | 2<<COM1B0;
```

Explanation of above code [here](https://www.re-innovation.co.uk/docs/fast-pwm-on-attiny85/). These calls enable FastPWM.

I checked the [Arduino API reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/), but not sure which are the equivalent to above. How to determine?

Comment: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is highly unlikely there would be direct 1:1 functions that implement such discrete operations. Simply because such operations are pretty unique to a single family of microcontrollers. They are too low-level for an API to even consider wanting them.

Instead, there are higher level functions which may, if the chip requires it, include those operations.

The operations you list are all related to PWM, so the higher level function that would encompass them would be `analogWrite()`.

Comment: Man, you're good! But, these fx are specifically to enable *FastPWM*. Any higher-level calls for FastPWM? thx!

Comment: Not that I am aware of in the standard Arduino API. We have them [in the chipKIT API](https://github.com/chipKIT32/chipKIT-core/blob/master/pic32/libraries/Examples/examples/Analog/AnalogWriteFrequencyAndResolution/AnalogWriteFrequencyAndResolution.ino), and it's something we'd like to see adopted upstream, but alas not yet.

Comment: sweet! Chipkit is for programming AVR's with Java?

Comment: What on earth would give you that impression? chipKIT is for programming PIC32s with the Arduino API.

Comment: Why on Earth would you mention a pic library in an Arduino question?

Comment: It's not a library. It's a core. For the Arduino IDE. To implement the Arduino API. Like the DUE core or the ESP8266 core or the Maple core... OR... the ATTiny core. That's not Arduino. That's a third party core that implements the Arduino API. Exactly like chipKIT, just for a different architecture.

Comment: Ok, you mentioned ChipKIT API. i was not familiar with it. I assumed it had some relevance to this question. Your reply "What on earth would give you that impression" was unnecessarily disrespectful-- you spoke to me like i'm stupid. But i'm not stupid, i'm just unfamiliar with ChipKIT. No matter-- treating people like they're stupid is standard behavior for many people on stackexchange, including you too we see. Nothing unusual about it.

Comment: I was just surprised you got java from it somehow. I'd love to know the thought processes that resulted in Java...

Comment: i prolly saw java mentioned someplace in connection with chipKIT. My misunderstanding. http://chipkit32.github.io/chipKIT-core/core_how_to_hack_chipkit_core.html